# How to use the on_press function with a touchscreen in kivy?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, kivy

I have a raspberry pi 7" touch, and I have been building a kivy application on it. But when the user clicks on the button and the `on_press` method should start but nothing happens. The cursor moves along the screen with the touch input but nothing is selected.

I already changed the `config.ini` for kivy so it supports the touchscreen.

Comment: Perhaps you should try using `on_press` instead of `on_pres`.

Comment: I was using the on_press function, just a little typing mistake here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the config.ini and checked it again.
But this time I copied/pasted the code which you can find below and it worked.

```
mouse = mouse
mtdev_%(name)s = probesysfs,provider=mtdev
hid_%(name)s = probesysfs,provider=hidinput
```